# Identify upside down question mark in a string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a for loop that looks at every character in a string, the purpose is to eliminate some characters.  For example one comparison that works is...

```
if(str[i] == '!'){str[i] = NULL;}
```

I also need to eliminate the upside down question mark.  I tried several things including some hex codes and the following.

```
if(str[i] == 191){str[i] = NULL;}
```

Here, I get an error that says, "comparison of constant 191 with expression of type 'value_type' is always false."  What am I missing here?  How can I catch the upside-down question mark?

Comment: Setting a character of a `std::string` to `NULL` does *not* eliminate it from the string.

Comment: Keep in mind that ¿ may not be character 191. Look up _character encodings_. ASCII is common but not universal, ASCII extensions come in about a thousand different variants most of which do not have ¿.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string's `value_type` is most likely `char`, which might or might not be signed on your platform.

If it's signed, `CHAR_MAX` would be 127... you see the problem when comparing that with 191? That is what the compiler is complaining about.

There are several ways around this.

The most roughshod one would be to *cast* the constant to `value_type`.

More elegant (but depending on your compiler's features) would be to actually write `'¿'` in your source and make sure your editor and your compiler agree on the encoding used by the source file.

While the standard only requires support for a subset of the ASCII-7 characters in source (minus backticks, `$` and `@`), implementations are free (and usually quite capable) of supporting other encodings.

For GCC, the option would be `-finput-charset=...`, which defaults to UTF-8.

All this is, of course, assuming that your source and your **input** are agreeing on their respective encodings as well. Being on the same codepage, so to speak. ;-)

---

All that being said, if you're handling international characters in your application, you might want to take a look at the [ICU library](http://icu-project.org) and full Unicode support.

Comment: Thank you.  That is helpful.